# One instance of Airflow or multiple?

Tags: airflow

I'm looking into airflow and I have upwards of 10 projects that could use airflow.

Would it be better to have one instance of airflow for all these projects or each project has its own instance?

For context, each project has its own server setup.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a central Airflow instance, that will save you the cost of maintenance and logging. Airflow is designed in a way to host a number of dependent and independent workflows, so keeping it separate for separate projects doesn't make sense.

If your team size increases you can make use of [Airflow's security features](http://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/security.html) for fine grained access control.

Comment: Thanks for your response!